# How to filter the array of records per model name ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

Suppose I have hashes of elements and I need to filter out the results based on the class names in them.

so, if records contains elements of PrivateSchool, I can pass PrivateSchool records to its respective partial.

If records contains elements of Teacher, I can pass Teacher records to its respective partial.

So, here is the code for partails:

```
<% if params[:tab] && params[:tab] == "featured" %>
    <%= render partial: "featured", locals: {featured: @results} %>
<% elsif params[:tab] && params[:tab] == "schools" %>
    <%= render partial: "schools", locals: {schools: @results}  %>
<% elsif params[:tab] && params[:tab] == "playlists" %>
    <%= render partial: "playlists", locals: {playlists: @results}  %>
<% elsif params[:tab] && params[:tab] == "quizzes" %>
    <%= render partial: "quizzes", locals: {quizzes: @results}  %>
<% elsif params[:tab] && params[:tab] == "teachers" %>
    <%= render partial: "teachers", locals: {teachers: @results}  %>
<% end %>
```

If I do `<%= @results.inspect%>` it outputs below:

```
    [#<LessonPlan id: 9, title: "advance java", description: "advance java",
 notes: "advance java", subject_id: 2, teacher_id: 1, created_at: "2016-11-11 
09:29:20", updated_at: "2016-11-11 09:29:20", is_private: true, is_publish: 
false, user_id: 3, publish_date: nil, popularity_count: 0, is_special: false, 
private_class_id: nil>, #<Quiz id: 1, title: "java history", 
time_limit_in_minutes: 5, are_multiple_attempts_allowed: true, score_to_keep: 
"highest", number_of_attempts_allowed: 4, student_see_quiz_score: 
"after_each_attempt", show_one_question_at_a_time: true, is_private: false, 
available_from_date_time: "2016-11-08 17:13:00", available_due_date_time: 
"2016-11-10 17:18:00", instructions: "<p>java basics</p>", lesson_plan_id: 3, 
user_id: 3, publish_date: "2016-11-09 12:14:04", created_at: "2016-11-09 
12:14:04", updated_at: "2016-11-09 12:19:25", is_publish: true, subject_id: 3, 
teacher_id: 1, popularity_count: 1, show_answers: "after_the_due_date">, 
#<LessonPlan id: 4, title: "basics of java", description: "basics of java", 
notes: "basics of java", subject_id: 2, teacher_id: 1, created_at: "2016-11-07
 13:04:24", updated_at: "2016-11-10 10:40:54", is_private: false, is_publish: 
false, user_id: 3, publish_date: "2016-11-09 08:08:41", popularity_count: 0, 
is_special: false, private_class_id: nil>, #<Quiz id: 6, title: "java modern",
 time_limit_in_minutes: 155, are_multiple_attempts_allowed: true, 
score_to_keep: "latest", number_of_attempts_allowed: 9, 
student_see_quiz_score: "after_last_attempt", show_one_question_at_a_time: 
true, is_private: true, available_from_date_time: "2017-02-02 01:11:00", 
available_due_date_time: "2017-02-27 01:11:00", instructions: "<p>java modern 
java modern java modern java modern...", lesson_plan_id: 3, user_id: 3, 
publish_date: "2016-12-22 20:37:35", created_at: "2016-12-22 20:37:35", 
updated_at: "2017-02-09 20:11:38", is_publish: false, subject_id: 3, 
teacher_id: 1, popularity_count: 0, show_answers: "after_the_due_date">, 
#<Quiz id: 4, title: "Java quiz v1", time_limit_in_minutes: 180, 
are_multiple_attempts_allowed: true, score_to_keep: "latest", 
number_of_attempts_allowed: 6, student_see_quiz_score: "after_last_attempt", 
show_one_question_at_a_time: false, is_private: false, 
available_from_date_time: "2016-11-21 12:48:00", available_due_date_time: 
"2016-11-23 12:48:00", instructions: "<p>Java quiz v1</p>\r\n<p 
style=\"margin: 0px;\"><!--E...", lesson_plan_id: 8, user_id: 3, publish_date: 
"2016-11-14 07:18:41", created_at: "2016-11-14 07:18:41", updated_at: 
"2016-12-11 14:21:46", is_publish: false, subject_id: 3, teacher_id: 1, 
popularity_count: 0, show_answers: "after_the_quiz">, #<Quiz id: 3, title: 
"java basics", time_limit_in_minutes: 4, are_multiple_attempts_allowed: true, 
score_to_keep: "highest", number_of_attempts_allowed: 10, 
student_see_quiz_score: "after_last_attempt", show_one_question_at_a_time: 
true, is_private: false, available_from_date_time: "2017-01-31 14:13:00", 
available_due_date_time: "2017-02-17 14:13:00", instructions: 
"<p>XXXXXXXXXXQQQQ</p>", lesson_plan_id: 8, user_id: 3, publish_date: 
"2016-11-10 20:27:32", created_at: "2016-11-10 20:27:31", updated_at: 
"2017-02-01 09:13:22", is_publish: false, subject_id: 3, teacher_id: 1, 
popularity_count: 1, show_answers: "after_the_quiz">, #<PrivateSchool id: 18, 
teacher_id: 39, user_id: 47, title: "Dr. Jasmine E McNair High School", 
short_description: "Dr. Jasmine E McNair High School", price_type: "paid", 
logo: "download.jpg", slug: "dr-jasmine-e-mcnair-high-school", created_at: 
"2016-12-13 20:18:28", updated_at: "2016-12-13 20:18:28">]
```

What I really want is to filter these records per model class name so I can filtered records and send the respective records to their partials rather than just show all of them in each partial.

Currently its showing all records in one partial which is wrong I need to filter them per partial so each partial will show his results not other model.

So,
If records belongs to LessonPlan all records from LessonPlan will go in lesson plan partial.

If records belongs to Teacher all records from Teacher will go in teacher partials .
and so on.

That's my requirement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like that :

```
hash = @results.group_by(&:class)
```

then :

```
hash[LessonPlan] will give you a list of all the LessonPlan
```

**Edit :**

```
<%= render partial: "quizzes", locals: {quizzes: hash[Quiz]}  %>
```

**Explanation :**
First step. We create as Hash based by the Class of the object. To accomplish that we use the Ruby method 'group_by' for Enumerable.
@results.group_by(&:class) is equivalent of @results.group_by {|result| result[:class]}
Then we can easily access the value of each hash by the class name. hash[Quiz] will return all the Quiz objects.

Comment: Yes please explain your answer as well how this code is working so it will help me and other future readers.

Answer (score 0):

Results can be filtered using the [select](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select) method:

```
@results.select { |r| r.is_a?(LessonPlan) } # etc.
```

Therefore your view can look like this:

```
<%= render partial: "lesson_plans", locals: {
  lesson_plans: @results.select { |r| r.is_a?(LessonPlan) }
} %>
```

Comment: And how I can assign them in: `<%= render partial: "featured", locals: {featured: @results} %>`

Comment: @LearningROR you can call this filter in partial statement:
`<%= render partial: "lesson_plans", locals: {featured: @results.select { |r| r.is_a?(LessonPlan) }} %>`